# Symbol of open set in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

In [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset), a way to create symbol of an open set is suggested using LaTeX or as appearing in the origina picture:

[image]

My university required me to write in word my document (strange indeed) and I need to use the symbol of an open set. How can I define it in word?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a proper way to define symbols in Word, but for a given size you can usually construct something using an EQ field, e.g.

{ EQ \o(⊆,⦁)}

where the { } are the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word, the subset symbol is Unicode 0x2286 (Subset Of Or Equal To), and the dot is Unicode 0x2981 (Z Notation Spot), both from the Cambria Math font. In this case the subset symbol was formatted as 12pt, and I had to select the dot and format the font to 10pt, raised by 1.5pt to fit it reasonably neatly inside the subset symbol. You can shift the dot to the right hand end of the subset symbol using. Anything else would probably require more fiddling around in the Font Format dialog box.

{ EQ \o\ar(⊆,⦁)}

Just in case these symbols do not get through to your display, the first field code is

{ EQ \o(a,b)}

where a is Unicode character 0x2286 and b is Unicode character 0x2981.

EQ fields only really work within Word documents and for printing. They may not work when saved as PDF and they almost certainly won't work when saved as HTML. This one should work within a Math Equation (using the editor in Word 2007 and later) but you would have to check. If you need several different sizes, your best bet is to create separate EQ fields manually (they almost certainly wont' scale), set them up as autocorrects or autocorrects for easy insertion, and ensure that you modify them as necessary if you resize the surrounding text.